# when does the fact that the normal bundle $N(X)$ is trivial imply that the tangent bundle $TX$ is trivial too?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\varphi: X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ be an submanifold immersed in $\mathbb{R}^N$, then everybody knows that $T\mathbb{R}^N\vert_X$= T(X)$\oplus N(X)$. It is clear that $T\mathbb{R}^N \vert_X$ is a trivial bundle over $X$. My question is: if we know that $N(X)$ is a trivial vector bundle over X does this implies that $TX$ is trivial?

I know that in the general case ($X$ a submanifold of a Riemannian manifold $M$) $N(X)$ trivial does not implies that $TX$ is trivial, my guess is that the answer to my question is NO, however the fact $T\mathbb{R}^N \vert_X$ is a trivial bundle and $N(X)$ is a sub bundle makes me feel that there might be a chance for $TX$ to be trivial.

Basic linear algebra shows that if {$v_1,..v_q$} is a global orthonormal frame of $N(X)$ then locally we can produce a local orthonormal frame for $TX$, however I think that there are problems if we try to construct a global frame for $TX$, however I am not sure if using that $T\mathbb{R}^N \vert_X$ is trivial we can construct such a global frame for $TX$.

Many thanks for you help math folks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal bundle being trivial implies that the tangent bundle is *stably* trivial (which means, by definition, that its sum with some trivial bundle is trivial). This implies, for example, that all of its Stiefel-Whitney and Pontryagin classes vanish, but in general it does not imply that the tangent bundle is trivial.

The simplest example is $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. The normal bundle is trivial because the outward-pointing normal is a trivialization of it, but the tangent bundle is still nontrivial; this is the [hairy ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem). Slightly more generally, the normal bundle of the usual embedding of the closed orientable surface $\Sigma_g$ of genus $g$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is trivial (again the outward-pointing normal is a trivialization), but the tangent bundle of $\Sigma_g$ is trivial iff $g = 1$ (e.g. by computing its Euler class).

Comment: It's worth noting that the existence of stably trivial bundles that aren't trivial implies that the operation of direct sum of vector bundles is not cancellative in the sense that $V_1 \oplus W \cong V_2 \oplus W$ does not imply $V_1 \cong V_2$.